# Eclipse error: org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:445)

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, sdf, suitecloud

I just integrated SuiteCloud IDE in Eclipse.
After successful installation, I still cannot create a new SuiteCloud Project: Account Customization.
Please see error message below:

```
Error
Fri May 15 04:35:02 SGT 2020
org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:445)
org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1033)
com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.wizards.newnetsuiteproject.NewNetSuiteProjectWizard.finishAccountCustomizationProject(NewNetSuiteProjectWizard.java:138)
com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.wizards.newnetsuiteproject.NewNetSuiteProjectWizard.performFinish(NewNetSuiteProjectWizard.java:118)
org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:832)
org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:472)
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:130)
org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

Windows 10 Pro x64

Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers, Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0), 
Build id: 20200313-1211

SuiteCloud IDE 2020.1.0 - https://system.netsuite.com/download/suitecloud-sdk/ideplugin/eclipse/20.1

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTbPk.png)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMQ6M.png)

Comment: Is that the whole message?

Comment: That's just a type name. Add the entire log entry to the question itself.

Comment: Was there a Cause by section after?

Comment: What do you mean by Cause by section? I dont see any reference to that

Comment: Lines after this stack trace that start with "Caused by" followed by another stack trace. It says "Error", but it's not saying anything about the error.

Comment: No caused by, I checked every stack trace messages.. I added the Error Log screenshot on the question as well

Comment: Not being able to see them, the contents of Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers have changed quite a bit in the past year. Try installing the "WST Common UI" Feature, and if that doesn't help, restart from the Enterprise Java package.